# Connecting Active Document Table to Multi Selection List Box in VBA Word 365

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am wondering how I can populate information in a word table from an active document into the same document in a list box.

I did this is excel, and it worked because I could reference cells using listbox properties RowSource to link to the list box in Excel.

I cannot do this in word. How do I reference the table in word for my list box? Or will I have to use string? I have tried writing

listbox1.additem "Apple"

for example, and it does not show in the listbox.

Thank you!

Comment: Word cannot connect a listbox to a table in the way that Excel can connect to dat in a sheet. There are a number of different types of listbox in Word. They have different capabilities and need to be coded differently. If yours is an ActiveX listbox (either a normal listbox in a VBA form or a Legacy ActiveX checkbox in the surface of the document, you may find Greg Maxey's article at https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/populate_userform_listbox_or_combobox.html useful. Otherwise, say which type of listbox you are working with.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I abandoned word and went to excel.